# Issue with executing MySQL insert statement from Coldfusion 10 server

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am attempting to execute a MySQL MySQL insert statement from a Coldfusion 10 Server, which results in an Cold Fusion Error.

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="MySQLServer_2"> 
    INSERT INTO developer_website.debug
    (Value_INT,Value_STR)
    VALUES(1,'test');
</cfquery>

 Coldfusion error link - http://postimage.org/image/dazcm6bfr/
```

The MySQL insert statement works correctly when executed from MySQL Workbench.  Further, I confirmed that select statements executed on the Coldfusion 10 server work correctly.

```
INSERT INTO developer_website.debug 
(Value_INT,Value_STR) 
VALUES(1,'test'); 

<cfquery name="test" datasource="MySQLServer_2"> 
    SELECT * 
    FROM developer_website.debug;
</cfquery>
```

Next, I attempted to set the variable 'binlog-format' cfquery itself.

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="MySQLServer_2"> 
    SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';

    INSERT INTO developer_website.debug
    (Value_INT,Value_STR)
    VALUES(1,'test');

    SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'STATEMENT';
</cfquery>
```

Which resulted in a new CFE.

```
Coldfusion error link - http://postimage.org/image/7q4rjrhnv/
```

Finally, I attempted to set the 'binlog-format' in the 'MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini' file.

```
binlog-format = ROW
```

Again, the issue is not fixed.  I continue to receive the original CFE and the data is not being inserted.

I am seeking insight on the issue, specifically how to fix the issue or perhaps a workaround.  All constructive comments/insights/questions/(solutions) are welcome.

Specifications:
Coldfusion version: ColdFusion 10,282462
MySQL version: 5.5.29-log
MySQL Connector version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the DSN was set up correctly, a database was already specified. There is no reason to specify `developer_website.debug` as your table, and that is probably causing the issue. You should just be accessing `debug` as the table for that particular DSN.

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I greatly appreciate your input and will use your solution.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: MS-SQL server supports syntax like this: "INSERT INTO [developer_website].debug". MySQL may support this syntax as well.